# Какое разрешение использовать для планшетной версии при вёрстке?

Tags: css

Большинство сайтов, у которых адаптивная вёрстка, используют разрешение 768 для планшета. Но сейчас планшетов очень много и с разными разрешениями. Поэтому возник вопрос, нужно ли делать версии ещё для каких-то других разрешений планшетов, или можно ограничиться 768px?

Comment: а еще планшеты могут быть в вертикальном или горизонтальном положении

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше всего не фиксироваться на разрешении, а сделать небольшую резину. Например в диапазоне 600-900 пикселей. Тем самым вы сделаете отлично для всех планшетов.

Как показывает практика, резина в таком диапазоне не представляет никаких особых сложностей и требований к дизайну.